# Replace multiple property values with new variables

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm doing a little Shell/Bash automation and I have a properties file that I need to update with new values.

The property file is of the format: `key.name=value`. That is, if the property key has multiple words, they are separated by a period.

I have this method which is where I'm trying to take my new variables and replace the old ones. One of the problems I'm running in to is that the last call in the method will overwrite the previous edits...

I'm very new to shell/bash scripting and I'm not sure how the best way to accomplish multiple value replacements is with shell. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Old method**

```
modify_properties () {
  awk -F"=" -v new_var1="$variable1" '/property.name1/{$2=new_variable;print;next}1' template.properties > new.properties
  awk -F"=" -v new_var2="$variable2" '/property.name2/{$2=new_variable;print;next}1' template.properties > new.properties
  awk -F"=" -v new_var2="$variable2" '/property.name3/{$2=new_variable;print;next}1' template.properties > new.properties
}
```

**New method**

```
modify_properties () {
   awk -F"=" -v new_ip="$private_ip" -v new_dns="$public_dns" '/prop.internaladdress/{$2=new_ip}/prop.externaladdress/{$2=new_dns}/prop.hostname/{$2=new_dns}1' template.properties > new.properties
 }
```

Comment: Put all the awk script bits into a single awk script instead of three. Use `new.properties` in calls after the first one. etc.

Comment: I updated the method, but I want to change 3 different properties with 2 variables. Two of the properties will have the same varible (`variable2`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it all in one call to `awk`.

```
modify_properties () {
  awk -F"=" -v new_var1="$variable1" -v new_var2="$variable2" '/property.name1/{$2=new_variable}/property.name2/{$2=new_variable}/property.name3/{$2=new_variable}1' template.properties > new.properties
}
```

Also note how you don't really need the `;print;next` bits here though leaving it wouldn't really hurt anything.

Alternatively you could have used multiple temporary files with each call to `awk` using the previous output file.

Comment: Alright, so I'm trying to implement the 'one-call' `awk` version that you have shown. It's replacing the values, but it's also getting rid of the `=` signs in between each property/value. Do you know where that would be happening?

Comment: Your original had that problem too. You aren't setting `OFS` to `=` so awk is using the default space as separator. Add `-v OFS==` to the command.

Comment: Huh, interesting, did not know that. Awesome, thanks for the help. Appears to be working now